# Looping through file with lists is returning "none" with mapping but works when I test manually

Tags: python, list, loops, mapping

first time attempting Advent of Code with python and running into an issue with my loop. I've successfully been able to take the input file and break it into lists as shown below for the output.txt. I'm trying to map each list (per line) and append it to the new processed.txt file. When I run the same example (my mapping vs a list) it returns the correct results. Could someone point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance! :)

The loop of code that is isn't mapping:

```
with open (output_filename, 'r') as infile, open(processed_filename, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        items = line.split()
        mapped_items = []
        for item in items:
            if item in mapping:
                mapped_items.append(mapping[item])
            else:
                mapped_items.append(None)
        outfile.write(f"{mapped_items}\n")
```

output.txt contains:

```
['eight', 'one', 'two', 'eight', '7']
['3', 'five', '4', 's', '84', 'four', '9', 'r', 'tbz', 'll', 'g', 'gz']
['75', 'seven', 'z', 'drp', 'kv', '1', 'one', 'two']
```

processed.txt contains:

```
[None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

The test which outputs [8, 1, 2, 8, 7] correctly in console.

```
my_list = ['eight', 'one', 'two', 'eight', '7']

# Define the mapping
mapping = {
        'zero': 0,
        'one': 1,
        'two': 2,
        'three': 3,
        'four': 4,
        'five': 5,
        'six': 6,
        'seven': 7,
        'eight': 8,
        'nine': 9,
        '0': 0,
        '1': 1,
        '2': 2,
        '3': 3,
        '4': 4,
        '5': 5,
        '6': 6,
        '7': 7,
        '8': 8,
        '9': 9
    }

# Loop through the list and apply the mapping
mapped_list = []
for item in my_list:
    if item in mapping:
        mapped_list.append(mapping[item])
    else:
        # Handle the case where the item is not in the mapping
        mapped_list.append(None)  # or some default value

print(mapped_list)
```

Expected [8, 1, 2, 8, 7] from the first line but instead resulted in [None, None, None, None, None]

Comment: When you split the line, you get everything that was actually on that line, including the literal quotes and commas.   In other words, the first value in `items` will be **square bracket**-**single quote**-**e**-**i**-**g**-**h**-**t**-**single quote**-**comma**.

Comment: This would have been obvious with a bit of basic debugging to print the actual value.

Comment: For future questions, [please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [locate a specific problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) first and produce an [mre]. Generally we do not write answers that "find the bug" for you here; you are expected to **check** what went wrong first, by examining the results of each step of the code as it goes along. "When I run the same example (my mapping vs a list) it returns the correct results." - hint: do you call `.split` on the list?

Answer (score 0):

### short answer :

```
import ast

with open (output_filename, 'r') as infile, open(processed_filename, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        items  = ast.literal_eval(line) ## Convert the line  to a list
        mapped_items = []
        for item in items:
            if item in mapping:
                mapped_items.append(mapping[item])
            else:
                mapped_items.append(None)
        outfile.write(f"{mapped_items}\n")
```

#### Content of processed.txt:

```
[8, 1, 2, 8, 7]
[3, 5, 4, None, None, 4, 9, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, 7, None, None, None, 1, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `line.split()` it splits the string by white-space.
Meaning `items` is a list which contains list of space-separated strings for each line in the file:

```
[["['eight',", "'one',", "'two',", "'eight',", "'7']"],
["['3',", "'five',", "'4',", "'s',", "'84',", "'four',", "'9',", "'r',", "'tbz',", "'ll',", "'g',", "'gz']"],
["['75',", "'seven',", "'z',", "'drp',", "'kv',", "'1',", "'one',", "'two']"]]
```

You need to remove all of the formatting charterers in the original string (`'[]`) for the strings to match:
`['eight',` is not equal to `eight`.

You can do something like that:

```
        items = line.strip().replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace("'", '').split(', ')
```

Instead of:

```
        items = line.split()
```

##### processed.txt:

```
[8, 1, 2, 8, 7]
[3, 5, 4, None, None, 4, 9, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, 7, None, None, None, 1, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Great explanation ! but  using `ast .literal_eval`  is a simple and efficient solution

Comment: @HamzaNABIL appreciate your suggestion. While using `ast.literal_eval` is a solution, my answer was aimed to address the root issue with the OP's code, which was related to incorrect string formatting. While your suggestion provides an alternative approach, it doesn't directly address the original problem.

Comment: I appreciate your clarification , Thank you